# how do I make multiple divs width change dynamically with out overlapping when window size changes

Tags: html, css

I have a div with three divs inside of different width. when my window size changes it is overlapping each other.How do I make content remain without overlapping when window size changes.
Here is my code.

```css
#topBarContainer{
   background-color: blue; 
}

#topBarLeft{
    width: 14%;
    text-align: center;
}
#topBarMiddle{
    width: 26%;    
    text-align: center;
}
#topBarRight{
    width: 60%;
    text-align: right;
}
.topBar {
  margin-right: -4px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topBarContainer">
    <!--TopBar-->
    <div id="topBarLeft" class="topBar">
        <input type="button" ng-click="newMenuType('message')"  value="New" id="newButton">     
    </div>
    <!--Top Bar Middle-->
    <div id="topBarMiddle" class="topBar">
        <div class="searchBoxContainer">
        <i class="fa fa-search fa-flip-horizontal" id="searchBoxIcon">&nbsp;</i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Inbox" class="searchBox" ng-model="searchEmail" />
        </div>          
    </div>
    <!--Top Bar Right-->
    <div id="topBarRight" class="topBar">
        <div>   
            <div class="loginRow">Hi{{loginName()}}</div> 
            <div ng-if="emailIcon()"  class="iconRow">
                <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="emailIcon()" class="iconRow">
                <i class="fa fa-reply-all"></i>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="emailIcon()"  class="iconRow" >
                <i class="fa fa-reply fa-flip-horizontal"></i>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="!isDeletedView() && emailIcon()" class="iconRow">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is looking good with normal window when I resize window it is overlapping all.leftBar takes 14%and middle bar takes 26% and rest for the right container.
I am spenting days to fix this. I need to align all so that all 3 sections display in the same line.

Comment: Not a real answer, but why don't you use a responsive framework, like http://getbootstrap.com/, for example? :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `display:flex` from `flexbox`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
#topBarContainer {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
}
#topBarLeft {
  width: 14%;
  text-align: center;
}
#topBarMiddle {
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  width: 35%
}
#topBarRight {
  text-align: right;
  background: green;
  flex: 1
}
#topBarRight > div {
  display: inline-flex
}
.topBar {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
#topBarRight >div:last-of-type {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="topBarContainer">
  <!--TopBar-->
  <div id="topBarLeft" class="topBar">
    <input type="button" ng-click="newMenuType('message')" value="New" id="newButton">
  </div>
  <!--Top Bar Middle-->
  <div id="topBarMiddle" class="topBar">
    <div class="searchBoxContainer">
      <i class="fa fa-search fa-flip-horizontal" id="searchBoxIcon">&nbsp;</i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search Inbox" class="searchBox" ng-model="searchEmail" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Top Bar Right-->
  <div id="topBarRight" class="topBar">
    <div>
      <div class="loginRow">Hi{{loginName()}}</div>
      <div ng-if="emailIcon()" class="iconRow">
        <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="emailIcon()" class="iconRow">
        <i class="fa fa-reply-all"></i>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="emailIcon()" class="iconRow">
        <i class="fa fa-reply fa-flip-horizontal"></i>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="!isDeletedView() && emailIcon()" class="iconRow">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> 
      </div>
      <div ng-show="canMoveToFolder()" class="iconRow" ng-mouseover="newIcon = true" ng-mouseleave="newIcon = false"> <i class="fa fa-folder-o"> </i> 
        <div ng-if="newIcon" id="newItemOptions">
          <label class='newItemLabel' ng-click="moveMessageToFolder(3)">Inbox</label>
          <label class='newItemLabel' ng-click="moveMessageToFolder(4)">Sent</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much . it resolved my issue.working good.I was adding one more icon after trash icon .I am adding envelope folder and when we click on that icon it show the options like inbox ,sent under that icon. how do I achieve that functionality?

Comment: <div ng-show="canMoveToFolder()" class="iconRow"   ng-mouseover="newIcon = true" ng-mouseleave="newIcon = false">
                <i class="fa fa-folder-o"> </i> 
               <div ng-if="newIcon" id="newItemOptions">
                    <label class='newItemLabel' ng-click="moveMessageToFolder(3)">Inbox</label>
                    <label class='newItemLabel' ng-click="moveMessageToFolder(4)">Sent</label>
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: this is not showing options under that icon. could you help me on this.

Comment: @hanu see updated answer, I just add the div you wrote in your comment

Comment: thank you so much for your code sample .it worked for me. I have one more last question on this.I am using md-button at topBarLeft. this button is not aligning and overlapped when the window size reduces.this is my code.<div id=opBarLeft" class="topBar"><md-button="md-raised" type="button"  ng-click="newMenuType('message')" value="New" id="newButton">New</md-button></div>. what properties do i have to add to this button to not to overlap?

Comment: And can't reproduce the issue because that is an angular button

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is what you are looking for but if you put your searchBoxContainer in display:flex; it shud solwe the problem cause it puts your searchBoxIcon in front of the searchBox it self

you have to pu in your css

```
.searchBoxContainer{
  display:flex;
}
```

```css
#topBarContainer{
   background-color: blue; 
}

#topBarLeft{
    width: 14%;
    text-align: center;
}
#topBarMiddle{
    width: 26%;    
    text-align: center;
}
#topBarRight{
    width: 60%;
    text-align: right;
}
.topBar {
  margin-right: -4px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.searchBoxContainer{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="topBarContainer">
    <!--TopBar-->
    <div id="topBarLeft" class="topBar">
        <input type="button" ng-click="newMenuType('message')"  value="New" id="newButton">     
    </div>
    <!--Top Bar Middle-->
    <div id="topBarMiddle" class="topBar">
        <div class="searchBoxContainer">
        <i class="fa fa-search fa-flip-horizontal" id="searchBoxIcon">&nbsp;</i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Inbox" class="searchBox" ng-model="searchEmail" />
        </div>          
    </div>
    <!--Top Bar Right-->
    <div id="topBarRight" class="topBar">
        <div>   
            <div class="loginRow">Hi{{loginName()}}</div> 
            <div ng-if="emailIcon()"  class="iconRow">
                <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="emailIcon()" class="iconRow">
                <i class="fa fa-reply-all"></i>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="emailIcon()"  class="iconRow" >
                <i class="fa fa-reply fa-flip-horizontal"></i>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="!isDeletedView() && emailIcon()" class="iconRow">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are all elements moved right with that negative margin on the `.topBar` class? I would just erase that, and add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.topBar` (just to be on the safe side for percentage widths and heights).

So you'd have

```
.topBar {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```